# Not Identified By ImageMagick Error when there is a space in the filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, imagemagick, paperclip

I am getting the width and height of an image stored on Amazon S3 using Paperclip as follows:

```
Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(user.avatar.url)
```

It has been working fine, but it is erroring on an image that has a space in the filename:

```
Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: my_amazon_s3_path_is_here/Martian landslide.jpg?1294675113 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

The image loads okay when you go to the URL in a browser. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that images without a space in their filename work fine, so it's not an issue with Imagemagick/Paperclip setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to URL Encode the url's? eg replace spaces with `%20`

Comment: This seemed like it would fix it, but for some reason it doesn't. I'll edit the results into the question.

Comment: Actually I just made a mistake, that works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ben: no problem. I had previously run into issues with spaces when using S3 in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you see:

```
not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

It means ImageMagick isn't set up correctly. Are other images working correctly?

Have you tweaked this setting yet?

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
```

It needs to point to the location where identify is installed. From the command line, you can determine this with:

```
which identify
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ImageMagick is set up correctly as it is working correctly on any image that doesn't have a space in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and file 'Снимок экрана от 2013-02-28 14:36:49.png' returns the same error. But it works correctly on heroku. So I think the problem is in ImageMagick